# Start javascript promise bluebird chain in way that handles errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

The motivation for this is to be able to catch all possible errors with the ending `.catch`, even ones that happen in initial synchronous code.

I want to start my promise chain like so:

```
const bbPromise = require('bluebird');
bbPromise.do(() => {
    someTask(); // Could throw
    return someVar.doSomeOtherTaskAsync();
})
.then((result) => {
    // Do something with result
})
.catch((err) => {
    console.log('err: ', err);
});
```

Is there a function that works like `bbPromise.do` function? `bbPromise.resolve` just gives me the whole lambda function that was passed in, unexecuted.

I know I could do something like this:

```
bbPromise.bind({}).then(() => {
    someTask(); // Could throw
    return someVar.doSomeOtherTaskAsync();
})
...
```

or even:

```
new bbPromise((resolve, reject) => {
    someTask(); // Could throw
    return someVar.doSomeOtherTaskAsync().then(resolve).catch(reject);
})
...
```

But these are a little indirect. Is there a good way to start a promise chain by just executing a function that could return a promise, and that has errors caught in the ending `.catch`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for [`Promise.try`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.try.html). `Promise.resolve` is appropriate when you have a value already and want to build a promise chain from it, but if you want to run some code that may throw, use `Promise.try` instead.

`try` takes and executes a function, dealing with any *synchronous* exception in the same manner as `then` would. You would end up with something like:

```
bbPromise.try(someTask).then(() => {
  return someVar.doSomeOtherTaskAsync();
}).then((result) => {
  // Do something with result
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log('err: ', err);
});
```